# Get live quote from web url

Tags: android, json, web-services

I am writing below code to get json string from url and parse json string to get stock info in an android app. My code is given below:

```
url = new URL(in);
Log.e(STOCK,"comes here ..0 ");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();

String dataone = convertStreamToString(stream);

reader = new JSONObject(dataone);
Log.e(STOCK,"comes here ..1 ");

JSONObject data  = reader.getJSONObject("data");
previousClose = data.getString("previousClose");
lastPrice = data.getString("lastPrice");
low52 = data.getString("low52");
totalTradedValue = data.getString("totalTradedValue");

Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,lastPrice,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,totalTradedValue,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

But I am getting exception after opening url, I have added internet permission in Android Manifest xml.

Comment: You should post your web url or post the response from that url. Without that, we can't do much to help you.

Comment: Post `dataone` JSON  string with question

Comment: in = http://live-nse.herokuapp.com/?symbol=INFY and dataone = {"lastUpdateTime":"31-MAR-2015 13:41:01","tradedDate":"31MAR2015","data":[{"extremeLossMargin":"5.00","cm_ffm":"2,22,411.60","bcStartDate":"-","change":"-16.00","buyQuantity3":"33","sellPrice1":"2,212.00","buyQuantity4":"121","sellPrice2":"2,212.10","priceBand":"No Band","buyQuantity1":"32","deliveryQuantity":"7,67,169","buyQuantity2":"1","sellPrice5":"2,213.40"}]}